# Has anyone ever made a plugin for the stock Android browser?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, stock-browser, browser-add-ons

Based on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960050/how-to-develop-plugins-for-the-native-android-browser), there's a possibility to develop for the native/stock Android browser. But it doesn't seem developers are latching onto creating at least some plugins for it. So for my question, I want to know if there exists some stock browser plugins already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one plugin exists. Adobe flash.
Note that plugins and extensions are not the same. The default AOSP browser doesn't support extensions.

Comment: Ahh thank you for clarifying my confusion. I essentially thought they're the same but only had varying terms.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's what you're after as it's a big commercial plugin that's unlikely to tell you much, but the [Flash Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer) springs to mind as the only browser plugin that I know of.